# Adyen Drop-In Payment Gateway library for React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, payment-gateway, adyen

Anyone, please suggest a perfect library for Adyen Drop-In payment library for React Native platform?

We tried the below library. But we couldn't find clear documentation.

- https://github.com/mkharibalaji/react-native-adyen-payment

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a soltution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently do not have official support for React Native. However, we do have an example integration in [our public archive over here](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-react-native-online-payments).

You could inspire yourself from some of the maintained examples [here](https://github.com/adyen-examples) to complete your own integration.

If you have specific questions, I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: Thanks @jlengrand. We are looking to integrate Adyen drop-in payment in our app. Is there any example integrations on your public archive for Drop-in? Also when can we expect the official documentation for React Native? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They have an official repo here (Beta version) https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-react-native